# Decomposing absolute value terms

Tags: linear-algebra, absolute-value

I have something like the following term:

---

7x<sub>1</sub> + 9x<sub>2</sub>  + | 10 - 7x<sub>1</sub> | + | 15 - 11x<sub>2</sub> |

I want to make it into something like this:

---

Ax<sub>1</sub> + Bx<sub>2</sub> , where A and B are constants

For two values x1 and x2, it is ok to try out both positive and negative values. However, I have 18 such terms and the coefficient for these xs' need to be used in a linear optimization problem in Matlab. Is there a way to achieve the above?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear: please clarify. Also, is there a plus or minus sign inside "$9x_2 5x_2$"?

Comment: I corrected the expression now.

Comment: That's better, though your question is still not clear. Is that expression in one of the linear constraints or the linear function to optimize? If to optimize, it is no longer linear and many of the theorems of linear programming would no longer apply.

Answer (score 0):

In general, there is no way to simplify such an expression to a linear expression $Ax_1+Bx_2$.

Here is a single-variable example using $f(x)=x+|x|$.

[image]

Clearly there is no way to simplify that to $f(x)=Ax$ or even $f(x)=Ax+B$. You would need a piece-wise definition, which is what you are trying to avoid.

Here is a [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+z+%3D+7x+%2B+9y+%2B+abs%2810+-+7x%29+%2B+abs%2815+-+11y%29) graph of the expression you gave:

[image]

Again, clearly there is no way to make that linear without a piece-wise definition.